# Recursive method on palindrome

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, palindrome

How should i analyze the runtime complexity with respect to the number of characters in a word.

Comment: You can use `word[-1]` to get the last character, you don't need to write `wordLenght - 1`.

Comment: How does the size of the string change each time it recurses? What is the relationship between the number of times it recurses and the original length?

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @Barmar Thats the problem, if the first word in word is not equal to the words lenght - 1, it returns false, so i do belive that this is an O(n^2). I dont understand the relationship between number of times it recurses and the first lenght, that why i needed help.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(n).

When you call the function, it returns immediately if one of the base case conditions is true.

Each time it recurses, it reduces the size of the `word` parameter by 2 characters (the first and last). So the maximum number of recursions is `len(word)/2`. When calculating complexity, we ignore constant coefficients, so the number of recursions is O(len(word)), meaning it's O(n).

Comment: Do we always ignore constant coefficients for complexity?

Comment: If thats the case then its very logical, thank you!

Comment: Yes, we do. Because we only care how the time changes as the input size increases. For O(n), if the inputs size doubles, the time doubles, and the coefficient is irrelevant.